# GridView inside a Container inside a Column doesn't fill up the rest of the screen

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

**The short version:**

GridView without enough items inside a Container doesn't fill up the rest of the screen.

[image: Bad result, not enough items] [image: With many items]

**The long version:**

My flutter app has a Column that should be scrollable, the Column has the following children:

- Container with an Image
- A SizedBox for spacing
- A Container with a GridView (for styling)

If the items inside my GridView are not enough, the color of the container (that contains the GridView) doesn't get applied to the end of the screen.

This my code structure:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0f2447),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // First Column Item
              Container(
                height: 250,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/ise.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      colors: [
                        Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0),
                        Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Second Column Item
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              // Third Column Item
              Container(
                // What I have tried
                // height: double.infinity, (Error: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.)
                // height: 500, (Works, but depends on the device height (can't be static) )
                // height: "the remaining height of the screen whatever it is"
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[100],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),
                child: GridView.count(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  children: currentList
                      .map(
                        (item) => ItemIcon(
                          label: item['title'],
                          icon: AssetImage(item['iconPath']),
                          changeView: changeView,
                          itemId: item['itemId'],
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

ItemIcon is a custom widget, it has an image with a fixed size and a Text with some padding.

Current list is simply as follows: (Just to avoid long code)

```
final List<Map<String, Object>> examples = [
 {
    'title': 'Test',
    'itemId': 0,
    'iconPath': 'assets/icons/icon.png',
 },
 ...
]
```

Apologies for the confusing title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to wrap the `third container` in [Expanded class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html), and it will do your job.

> Expanded takes up the remaining spaces in `Row/Column`.

**Code**

```
        Expanded(
           child: Container(
                // What I have tried
                // height: double.infinity, (Error: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.)
                // height: 500, (Works, but depends on the device height (can't be static) )
                // height: "the remaining height of the screen whatever it is"
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[100],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),
                child: GridView.count(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  children: currentList
                      .map(
                        (item) => ItemIcon(
                          label: item['title'],
                          icon: AssetImage(item['iconPath']),
                          changeView: changeView,
                          itemId: item['itemId'],
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ) 
        )
```

**Alternative**

You can anyway rely on the previous code, and just play with the `height` using [MediaQuery class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html). This will keep the height uniformed to different device

```
              Container(
                // play with the floating number to get the desired height
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.61,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[100],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),
                child: GridView.count(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  children: currentList
                      .map(
                        (item) => ItemIcon(
                          label: item['title'],
                          icon: AssetImage(item['iconPath']),
                          changeView: changeView,
                          itemId: item['itemId'],
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              )
```

**Another Workaround for Landscape view**

You can use [Stack class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) for achieving uniformity. Make use of the **third widget as is**. Just use the `Stack` to align the items for your landscape view.
Please read about [Positioned class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html), which help you align your items in the view

So the view will be

```
Stack(
  Container with an Image
  // the last one comes on top of the first view
  // no sizedbox required since you can align the item using Positioned
  Positioned(
    top: use media_query_dimension,
    left: use media_query_dimension,
    right: use media_query_dimension, 
    bottom: use media_query_dimension.
    child: A Container with a GridView (for styling)
  )
)
```

Comment: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
space in the vertical direction.  Widget cause: Column

Comment: Hey @AnisBenna could you please give the height and width to the `Container()` wrapping your `SingleChildScrollView` as ```height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height``` and ```width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width```. Rest use my code only. Let me know if that works out :) Also, add ```mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min``` to your `Column()` wrapping the items. I hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: Still facing the same error. I've tried following the provided suggestion but it only fixes the error (UI issue is still there) Here's the suggestion: Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and
then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
constraints provided by the parent.

Comment: Did it work out for you @AnisBenna The suggestion which you pointed out?

Comment: It removes the error, but the Container still doesn't fill up the remaining height

Comment: @AnisBenna You can do  one thing, in the `Container()` itself, which wraps the `GridView()`. Use `MediaQuery` to give the height. What this will do is, it will adjust the height as per the device only. Like on different device you will see the same UI. Just try giving height using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5`. Play with the `floating` number. It goes from `0-1`. So you can make changes and set the height. Now with this you can check in another screens, and then you will be able to see the same uniformed height. Let me know

Comment: It works if the number of items in the GridView is less than the amount displayed on screen. However if there are many items, the first Container (with the image) will always be persisent when scrolling down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219620/discussion-between-alok-and-anis-benna). @AnisBenna

Comment: Hey @AnisBenna I have added more information to the answer. Feel free to make use of  it :)